# Does this sequence converge or diverge? $a_n = (-1)^n\frac{n^2+n+2}{2n^2+3n+4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We had this question on an exam and I don't know if I got it right or not.  We were asked to justify our answer.  I said the sequence diverges since the limit bounces between $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ but now I think I got it wrong.

Again, here is the sequence.

$a_n = (-1)^n\frac{n^2+n+2}{2n^2+3n+4}$

Comment: Does the $n$-th term converge to $0$?

Comment: You are asking for the sequence or for the series?

Comment: @LuisValerin the sequence

Comment: Ok then the result follows from the fact that $(-1)^n$ diverges, combining with the @T. Bongers answer and with the Theorem that i have enunciated below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2 + n + 2}{2n^2 + 3n + 4} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1 + \frac 1 n + \frac 2 {n^2}}{2 + \frac 3 n + \frac 4 {n^2}} = \frac 1 2 \ne 0$$

So $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ does not exist, and in particular is not zero.

Comment: Wait, I thought that a sequence could converge at a number other than $0$, but a series had to converge to $0$?

Comment: If a sequence converges, then the sequence of terms must converge to $0$. That's called the $n$-th term test, typically.

Comment: I'm not doubting that you're correct, just that I'm missing something major here.  I'm looking at the solution manual for my book which has a similar problem, except its positive.  $a_n=\frac{3+5n^2}{n+n^2}$ and it says this this series converges and $=5$

Comment: @inquisitor The *sequence* $a_n$ does converge. The series $$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n$$ does not.

Comment: Right (and thank you so much for your patience, this subject has been difficult for me), so in my answer on the test, was I correct to say the sequence diverges because of the $(-1)^n$?

Comment: @inquisitor Yes, the *sequence* of terms diverges because of the alternation between $\pm \frac 1 2$. The *series* diverges because the sequence of terms [does not converge to $0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Comment: OK, thank you, I understand 100% now!

Answer (score 1):

Does the $n$-th term converge to $0$? If not, you're done. Recall that if $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ converges then $$0=\lim (s_{n+1}-s_n)=\lim a_{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

In fact this limit diverges. Because if a limit exist, and is not zero, then the product of this with another limit that does not exist, also not exist.